# How to restore a CnosDB cluster in k8s?

Tags: cnosdb

I deployed a 1-meta & 3-tskv cnosdb cluster in k8s.
For some reason the meta node restarted, and then I couldn't get data from the cnosdb cluster.An example is as follows:
[image]

So is there any way to get him to work again without losing the previous data? I really don't want to redeploy it.